# How to create a dynamic page in an Android app

Tags: android

Recently was given the opportunity to create an Android app for my college group. But I was not satisfied with the event page. I wanted to create a dynamic page in which admin can update the upcoming events. On using URI the images were a bit off. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Actually we already have verification of gmail through firebase. The basic idea was to give a couple of emails the authority to add or delete the events. In addition of events, we wanted to give poster as an image and below that a button which would redirect to a page which would take details of an individual and store the data in a php file online.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create Event Page which can be changed dynamically, you should design a page such that, you give a provision of adding Events, displaying it and 
refreshing the UI.

I would suggest before start implementing an App, you should gather requirements, define the features of the App, Design the App and then go after implementing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase storage and Real-time database to store data and images. Also, create an admin application for changing the image.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can have provision to add an event, persist the event details by using either database or webservice, and updating the event.
2. The create event page can be made dynamic by having provisions to add/subtract event detail items from the screen. For example: Use can have a section saying Number of day(s) and a + button besides it to add details about each added day.
3. If you want only admin user to be able to add, update, and delete the event you can use role based login (for login again, you can use either database or webservice).

These are just rough ideas, but its necessary that you freeze the requirements before jumping into designing the app.